# Excel VBA with multiple pivot filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a pivot table and I am trying to create multiple filters on them using Excel VBA.

**Condition:**
I want all the PCC level 3 hence `PivotFields("PCC Level")=3` AND
I want the `PivotFields("TowerLevel3")="Global Transition Services"`

**Issue :**
 
`PivotFields("TowerLevel3")="Global Transition Services"` should populate when it is true for PCC Level 0,1,2,3.

```
Sub Macro2()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PCC3ActionPlan").PivotFields("Project PCC Level")
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("3").Visible = True
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PCC3ActionPlan").PivotFields("TowerLevel3")
        .PivotItems("Applications Consulting").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Applications Development, Maintenance, & Support").Visible = _
        False
        .PivotItems("Applications Management and Support").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Applications Modernization").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Business Intelligence and Data Warehousing").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Business Process Services").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Cloud (non-Oracle)").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Cloud (Oracle-based)").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Consulting & Systems Integration").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Enterprise Application Services").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Enterprise Deployment Team").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Enterprise Managed Security").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Global Healthcare Consulting").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Global Transition Services").Visible = True
        .PivotItems("Infrastructure & Technology Services").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Infrastructure Consulting Services").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Infrastructure Outsource Services").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Insite One (acquisition)").Visible = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It is recommended to indicate the version of Excel you are using by selecting the correct flag. While you do that, please compare how Pivot features change/improved/discarded from 2003 to 2015... [Check this as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19115086/1389394)